# Create and download an AWS ec2 keypair using python boto

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm having difficulty figuring out a way (if possible) to create a new AWS keypair with the Python Boto library and then download that keypair.

Comment: Instead of having Amazon create the keypair, I recommend creating the ssh key yourself and uploading the public key to EC2.  Here's an article I wrote about that: http://alestic.com/2010/10/ec2-ssh-keys  You should be able to use boto to perform the "ec2-import-keypair" API call.

Answer (score 11):

The Key object returned by the create_keypair method in boto has a "save" method.  So, basically you can do something like this:

```
>>> import boto
>>> ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
>>> key = ec2.create_key_pair('mynewkey')
>>> key.save('/path/to/keypair/dir')
```

If you want a more detailed example, check out https://github.com/garnaat/paws/blob/master/ec2_launch_instance.py.

Does that help?  If not, provide some specifics about the problems you are encountering.

Answer (score 3):

Same for Boto**3**:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

keypair_name = 'my_key'


new_keypair = ec2.create_key_pair(KeyName=keypair_name)

with open('./my_key.pem', 'w') as file:
    file.write(new_keypair.key_material)

print(new_keypair.key_fingerprint)
```