# boto: Creating and downloading an EC2 keypair

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I am trying to create and download a new SSH key using boto, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658578/create-and-download-an-aws-ec2-keypair-using-python-boto), and I am using the steps outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658766/1414455):

```
key_cass = conn.create_key_pair('cassandra_keypair')
key_cass.save('path/to/folder/'.encode('utf-8'))
```

In this case, it tells me that:

> TypeError: Can't mix strings and bytes in path components

When I remove the explicit encoding:

```
key_cass.save('path/to/folder/')
```

I get:

> TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

If it helps, I am using boto version 2.36.0 on Python 3.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Its mainly because you are using Python 3.x

In Python 3.x, String is not the same type as for Python 2.x

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471158/typeerror-str-does-not-support-the-buffer-interface)

Solution 1 : Run it in Python 2.x

Solution 2 : Use some typecasting  for the same

Hope it helps..

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @BhargavRao I've updated the answer, i'm new to stack overflow, please review the answer. Let me know any changes needs to be done